# Fail2ban - creating second sshd-jail for docker-container log does not work

Tags: docker, sshd, fail2ban

I have a Linux box on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and have a working fail2ban configuration (like on all my hosts).

In this case I setup a docker-container which acts as a sftp-server for several users - the docker-container has a running `rsyslogd` and writes login events to `/var/log/auth.log` - `/var/log` is mounted to the host-system to `/myapp/log/sftp`.

So I created a second sshd-jail with this config snippet in `jail.local`

```
[myapp-sftp]
filter=sshd
enabled = true
findtime = 1200
maxretry = 2
mode = aggressive
backend = polling
logpath=/myapp/log/sftp/auth.log
```

The logfile `/myapp/log/sftp/auth.log` is absolutely there and filled with a lot of failed login tries - from myself and others.

But the jail never gets triggered with a `found` log entry in `fail2ban.log`.
I already reset the fail2ban database ... and have no clue what might be wrong.

I tried `backend = polling` and the default `pyinotify`.

Checking with `fail2ban-regex` says that it matches..

```
# fail2ban-regex /myapp/log/sftp/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : sshd, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         maxlines : 1
Use      datepattern : Default Detectors
Use         log file : /myapp/log/sftp/auth.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 268 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   3) [64] ^Failed \S+ for invalid user <F-USER>(?P<cond_user>\S+)|(?:(?! from ).)*?</F-USER> from <HOST>(?: port \d+)?(?: on \S+(?: port \d+)?)?(?: ssh\d*)?(?(cond_user): |(?:(?:(?! from ).)*)$)
|   4) [29] ^Failed \b(?!publickey)\S+ for (?P<cond_inv>invalid user )?<F-USER>(?P<cond_user>\S+)|(?(cond_inv)(?:(?! from ).)*?|[^:]+)</F-USER> from <HOST>(?: port \d+)?(?: on \S+(?: port \d+)?)?(?: ssh\d*)?(?(cond_user): |(?:(?:(?! from ).)*)$)
|   6) [64] ^[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user <F-USER>.*?</F-USER> from <HOST>(?: port \d+)?(?: on \S+(?: port \d+)?)?\s*$
|  21) [111] ^<F-NOFAIL>Connection from</F-NOFAIL> <HOST>
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [642] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
`-

Lines: 642 lines, 0 ignored, 268 matched, 374 missed
[processed in 0.13 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 374 lines
```

and

```
# fail2ban-client status myapp-sftp
Status for the jail: myapp-sftp
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     0
|  `- File list:        /myapp/log/sftp/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned:     0
   `- Banned IP list:
```

```
# cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | grep myapp
2019-08-21 10:35:33,647 fail2ban.jail           [649]: INFO    Creating new jail 'wippex-sftp'
2019-08-21 10:35:33,647 fail2ban.jail           [649]: INFO    Jail 'myapp-sftp' uses pyinotify {}
2019-08-21 10:35:33,664 fail2ban.server         [649]: INFO    Jail myapp-sftp is not a JournalFilter instance
2019-08-21 10:35:33,665 fail2ban.filter         [649]: INFO    Added logfile: '/wippex/log/sftp.log' (pos = 0, hash = 287d8cc2e307c5f427aa87c4c649ced889d6bf6a)
2019-08-21 10:35:33,689 fail2ban.jail           [649]: INFO    Jail 'myapp-sftp' started
```

I really never get an expected `found` entry... nor a ban.
Any ideas are welcome.

```
# fail2ban-server -V
Fail2Ban v0.10.2

Copyright (c) 2004-2008 Cyril Jaquier, 2008- Fail2Ban Contributors
Copyright of modifications held by their respective authors.
```

log sample from `/myapp/log/sftp/auth.log`

```
Aug 21 14:03:13 a9ede63166d9 sshd[202]: Failed password for invalid user mapp from <HOST> port 41766 ssh2
Aug 21 14:03:13 a9ede63166d9 sshd[202]: Received disconnect from <HOST> port 41766:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Aug 21 14:03:13 a9ede63166d9 sshd[202]: Disconnected from <HOST> port 41766 [preauth]
Aug 21 14:03:49 a9ede63166d9 sshd[204]: Connection from <HOST> port 34722 on 172.17.0.3 port 22
Aug 21 14:03:49 a9ede63166d9 sshd[204]: Invalid user mapp from <HOST> port 34722
Aug 21 14:03:49 a9ede63166d9 sshd[204]: input_userauth_request: invalid user mapp [preauth]
Aug 21 14:03:49 a9ede63166d9 sshd[204]: error: Could not get shadow information for NOUSER
Aug 21 14:03:49 a9ede63166d9 sshd[204]: Failed password for invalid user mapp from <HOST> port 34722 ssh2
Aug 21 14:03:49 a9ede63166d9 sshd[204]: Received disconnect from <HOST> port 34722:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Aug 21 14:03:49 a9ede63166d9 sshd[204]: Disconnected from <HOST> port 34722 [preauth]
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is "solved". The docker container simply used a different timezone than the host and the logfile timestamps didnt contain the timezone.

So `fail2ban` assumed the timestamps were written in the same timezone as it´s running environment (on host) and didn´t interprete "old" log entries (2 hr. diff).

See https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2486

I simply set the host timezone to UTC now - but will try now to set rsyncd to use a timezoned dateformat